# Drain pipe clogged in tough spot

Tags: plumbing

After things thawed out in Texas, I found that my kitchen sink will not drain.  In checking the p-trap, I found the inside plumbing corroded and replaced all of it from sink drains (*double sink*) to stub-out.  I have run a snake through the stub-out and down to what seems to be the right angle under the slab.  I can not get past that, but there is nothing getting caught on the snake.  I just can't get it to turn another corner.

I dug up outside, removing a concrete step for access.  I have actually run a garden hose in about 10 feet downstream, and have another access hole 20 feet beyond, where I can see water running freely.  I have tried putting boiling hot water in the sink and plunging.  I sucked out a bit of grit and slime, but not much.  I need an idea on how I can go upstream from the Y shaped access hole.  Water left in the sink will drain overnight, with no sign that there is a leak.  I.e., it must be seeping slowly through the pipe.

[image]

Comment: If you can block the vent, then use a garden hose in the stub, or push it in further, to flush water through fast enough you might dislodge whatever... But if that is corroded as well then it’s a risk...

Comment: Is the pipe in the slab cast iron drain pipe or is this plastic, i.e., PVC or ABS?

Comment: The pipe is cast iron.  I was going to cut a hole with a hacksaw, but that is going to take a long, long time.  The old pipes that I left behind all seem very sound.  There is nothing more that I can remove by unscrewing- the stub-out is there to stay.  I had to break some of the fittings under the sink to get them off.  70 year old house.

Comment: Stop before you cause unnecessary damage. Don't start sawing the cast iron drain pipes. If the cast iron pipe is sound, you don't want to damage it. A professional plumber can probably snake this.

Comment: What size is the pipe at the 90?

Answer (score 2):

I think at this point, you should call in a plumber with a snake & camera to determine the problem with the drain pipe. Instead of cutting, flushing and making a big mess a plumber with a camera on his snake could quickly determine the problem and the fix needed. If you call in a professional tell him/her the size and type of the piping you are dealing with.

my 2 cents